# Where can I find stats for greater spirits and elementals?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

I have seen a lot of references to spirits and elementals which are strong enough to wipe mining crews and all, but I can't find a single place where they are described (except wood elementals in Creatures of barsaive)

Where are they?

Answer (score 4):

In Earthdawn 1st edition, Elementals should be in [*Magic: A Manual of Mystic Secrets* (1996)](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/45676/magic-manual-mystic-secrets).